# radio and radiolist flutter andriod studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Anyone can help me to solve this problem in the code, so I want to answer and correct the code in the android studio" `home.dart` named of file

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Color val;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: val,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter forms lesson 5'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Green'),
            Radio(
              value: Colors.green,
              groupValue: val,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  val = newValue;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text('Red'),
            Radio(
              value: Colors.red,
              groupValue: val,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  val = newValue;
                });
              },
            ),
            RadioListTile(
              title: Text('Orange'),
              value: Colors.orange,
              groupValue: val,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  val = newValue;
                });
              },
            ),
            RadioListTile(
              title: Text('Yellow'),
              value: Colors.yellow,
              groupValue: val,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  val = newValue;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code instead of code-image?

Comment: how can I put code

Comment: You  can update the question by clicking on `edit`

Comment: when I put my comment to show code it show me need more details

Comment: Yap, you need to describe the issue you are facing and put the code

Comment: now see my code

Comment: Aren't you using null-safety?

Answer (score 0):

In dart everything should be typed if at all possible. You can write it without typing but issues like this one will crop up. The problem you are seeing here is because your radio button is not typed. Here is an example of a radio button from the docs:

```dart
Radio<SingingCharacter>(
  value: SingingCharacter.lafayette,
  groupValue: _character,
  onChanged: (SingingCharacter newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _character = newValue;
    });
  },
)
```

In this case you can see in the declaration the `Radio` is typed as a `SingingCharacter` by writing `Radio<SingingCharacter>`. This lets the analyzer know that the `onChanged` value will also be a `SingingCharacter`.

In your code, it should be pretty simple to fix:

```dart
Radio<Color>(
  value: Colors.red,
  groupValue: val,
  onChanged: (Color? newValue) {
    if (newValue != null) {
      setState(() {
        val = newValue;
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Null newValue received!');
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: I tried but it is same problem

Comment: Looks like there was a null safety issue. I guess the docs havent been updated. It was complaining because the newValue is nullable and you are trying to assign it to a non null value. 

As a side note, youll need to set the initial value of val or it wont compile.